# Problems with TRIGGER and selecting query for product list after order

Tags: mysql, triggers

This is example of my code:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer(
CustID int not null,
primary key(CustID)
);

CREATE TABLE Products(
ProdID integer not null,
Quantity NUMERIC(3),
PRIMARY KEY(ProdID)
);

CREATE TABLE Orders(
Id INT not null,
Quantity NUMERIC(3),
Date date,
PRIMARY KEY(Id)
);
alter table Orders add OrdFK INT;
alter table Orders add constraint Ord_FK
foreign key (OrdFK) references Customer(CustID);
alter table Orders add ProdIdFK INT;
alter table Orders add constraint ProdId_FK
foreign key (ProdIdFK) references Products(ProdID);

insert into Products(ProdID, Quantity) values(1, 7);

CREATE TRIGGER  QuantityUpdate
AFTER INSERT
   ON Orders FOR EACH ROW
   
BEGIN
UPDATE Products p
SET p.Quantity = p.Quantity - New.Quantity 
WHERE p.ProdID = New.ProdIDFK

END$$
DELIMITER ;

INSERT into Orders(Id, Quantity, Date, ProdIDFK, OrdFK) values(1, 2, '2020/01/27', 1, 1);

SELECT Quantity from Products where ProdID = 1;
```

And then it shows the products quantity as it was in the beginning, without changing the quantity -2.
I think the problem is in...

```
SET p.Quantity = p.Quantity - New.Quantity 
WHERE p.ProdID = New.ProdIDFK
```

...but dunno what is exactly wrong:/ I tried to change New.ProdIdFK on New.ProdID and that didnt help. In Orders table ProdIdFK references to Products ProdID, and OrdFK references to Costumers CustID.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=acbc58e0d8cd5cd7aa51921f35dae8b3)

Comment: Why would you use numeric for decimal datatype? and in this case a decimal with 0 precision which suggests the datatype should be integer and possibly that the code is not mysql.

Comment: I set INT, set NUMERIC, doesnt matter, in both cases nothing happening:/